# OutOfMemoryError when reading single column from PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, out-of-memory, pg-jdbc

I'm trying to read one of columns from one of table from my locally installed PostgreSQL 10.3

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/vk", "postgres", "qwerty");
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
statement.setFetchSize(10);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select POST_CONTENT from VK_GROUP_POST");
System.out.println("rs is ready " + rs);
```

I run program with `-verbose:gc -Xmx512M` VM options.
Project has only dependency: `org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.1`

And I always get OOM error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
...
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2134)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:224)
at my.SaveRepostedToFile.main(SaveRepostedToFile.java:10)
```

Are there any way to avoid OOM?

Comment: Apparently you need to turn auto-commit off for fetch size to work - https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#fetchsize-example

Comment: @PavelHoral you are right. Create answer with your comment content